# Getting 'An error occurred: org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.replaceKey when tried to run the jmeter test in non gui mode with master and slave

Tags: jmeter

Getting

> 'An error occurred:
>   org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.replaceKey(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)'
>   when tried to run the jmeter test in non gui mode with master and
>   slave concept (jmeter version: 3.1, java: 7).

please suggest.
[image: jmeterlogfile]

[image: jmeter new log file]

Comment: Full stacktrace or jmeter.log file, please

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am using EC2 instance with docker images/continer(jmeter 3.1). Under bin folder not able to see jmeter.log file. Please suggest where can i see log files.

Comment: Try launching JMeter as `jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -Dserver_port=1099 -s -j jmeter.log`

Comment: Thanks @DmitriT. I have attached the jmeter.log file as screenshot in the original post. Please suggest.

Comment: This is clear now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have master and slave versions mismatch, one of them is JMeter 2.13 and the other one is JMeter 3.1.

Make sure you upgrade all JMeter instances to [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31) and the issue should be resolved.

Also make sure that Java version is the same, as you seem to have Java 7 on one machine and Java 8 on the other.

Reference: [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) User Manual Chapter:

> **Step 0: Configure the nodes**
>
> Make sure that all the nodes (client and servers) :
>
> - are running exactly the same version of JMeter.
> - are using the same version of Java on all systems. Using different versions of Java may work but is discouraged.

Comment: Thanks for the info. My docker files jmbase has 3.1 and master/slaves are also with 3.1(inheriting from jmbase) and java 8 is installed in all the machines. I have added the jmeter.log file screen shot, please guide.